# VBA can't get array to resize

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get my array to resize to the length of the number of sheets in my workbook but keep getting

> Subscript out of range

For context my sheet names are "Year XXXX"

```
Dim sheetsForCalendar() As Integer    

For Each Worksheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Dim i As Integer: i = 0
    Dim calendarYear() As String: calendarYear() = Split(CStr(Worksheet.Name))
    ReDim Preserve sheetsForCalendar(i)

    If calendarYear(0) = "Year" Then
        Dim calendarYearAsInt As Integer: calendarYearAsInt = calendarYear(1)
        sheetsForCalendar(i) = calendarYearAsInt
    End If

    i = i + 1
Next

For Each element In sheetsForCalendar
    MsgBox (sheetsForCalendar(element))
Next
```

Comment: I am using ReDim, (see line 5) and still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside other problems in your code, this here is wrong:

```
For Each element In sheetsForCalendar
    MsgBox (sheetsForCalendar(element))
Next
```

`element` takes the values in sheetsForCalendar, ie. `2015`, `2016` for example, it is not the index.
Either loop through `for n = 0 to UBound(sheetsForCalendar)` or just `MsgBox element`.

You should read on how to single-step through your code (F8 and place cursor over variables to see their content). This will help you find your errors easily (also how you 'mistreated' `i` as Mark Snyder pointed out).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you set i = 0 at the beginning of your For Each loop, so no matter how many sheets you have, the ReDim statement always uses the value 0.  If you move the Dim statement for variable i above the For Each statement, it should work better.  HTH